# $\mathbb{E}(\ln^+ \vert X \vert) < \infty \Longrightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert \geq e^{\alpha n})< \infty$ for all $\alpha >0 $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, expected-value

So $X$ is any non null complex random variable and $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ are independent clones of $X$.

From $\mathbb{E}(\ln^+ \vert X \vert) < \infty$ they conclude that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert \geq e^{\alpha n})< \infty$ for all $\alpha >0 $ and the analogous thing for the $= \infty $ case ($\mathbb{E}(\ln^+ \vert X \vert) = \infty \Longrightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\vert X \vert \geq e^{\alpha n})= \infty$).

So I know there is this alternative formula for the expected value but I thought it holds only for discrete random variables. So I am not sure how they get to this and also including this $\alpha$.

I have found online that $\mathbb{E} [X] = \int_0^\infty P[X \geq x]dx$ do they then use some approximation of the integral to get a sum? But I still can't figure out how this implies what I want?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for the following inequality for a real random variable $Y$:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} 1_{Y\geq n} \leq Y^+  \leq \sum_{n\geq 0} 1_{Y\geq n}.$$
Apply this to $Y=\ln|X|/\alpha$ and take expectation.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that for you $ln^+ = \log_{e}$, you obtain: $\mathbb{E} [ln ^+ |X|] = \int_0^\infty P[ln^+ |X| > x]dx=\int_0^\infty P[|X| > e^x]dx$ because $ln^+ |X| > x$ if and only if $|X| > e^x$. Now $\int_0^\infty P[|X| > e^x]dx \geq \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbb{1}_{[\alpha (n-1),\alpha n]} P[|X| > e^{\alpha n}]= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} P[|X| > e^{\alpha n}] \int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbb{1}_{[\alpha (n-1),\alpha n]} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} P[|X| > e^{\alpha n}] \alpha $ from which you get:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} P[|X| > e^{\alpha n}] < +\infty$$